# need to convert numbers to word in a text document

Tags: python

i want to change all numbers in a document to word. follow two functions detect numbers in string by pattern and convert it to word through num2word library.

```
import num2words
from re import sub

def _conv_num(match):
        word=num2words(match)
        return word

def change_to_word(text):
        normalized_text = sub(r'[^\s]*\d+[^\s]*', lambda m: _conv_num(m.group()), text)
        return normalized_text
```

when i use these two function by follow code

```
txt="there are 3 books"
change_to_word(txt)
```

python issue this error

```
  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

i tried to find some similar post but it seems that no body had same issue or i didn't search in proper way, so kindly help me with a solution or a link about it
regards

Comment: Your question is missing relevant information because the code you posted is incomplete, and is missing the bit that’s actually causing the error. It’s probably related to the fact that `get_number_pattern` doesn’t return a string.

Comment: i put the pattern in separate function for more clarity.  but now you can see it

Comment: @BramVanroy thank you it works but if the text have two number it make mistake, can you help to solve it, i am not familiar with this

Comment: Still works https://repl.it/@BramVanroy/CyanOrganicBrackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
import re

def _conv_num(match):
    return num2words(match.group())

def numbers_to_words(text):
    return re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', _conv_num, text)
```

- for clarity, import the whole regular expression library and use `re.sub()` instead of just `sub`
- no need for a lambda if your conversion function takes a match instead of a string
- use word boundary matchers (`\b`) in the regular expression
- more descriptive name for the main function